# Inner join issue to update in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables and trying to update time with delta in table-1 using inner join but I am facing an issue with my below query.

```
UPDATE Table-1
SET Table-1.Time = DATEADD(minutes,,table-2.delta,table-1.time)
FROM Table-1
INNER JOIN Table-2 ON Table-1.TynameName = Table-2.Typename 
                   AND Table1.Ordersequence >= table-2.ordersequence;
```

The time is getting updated for only ordernumber >4 (10-minutes) to order 9, and then delta updates for order 9 and greater for (5-minutes).

My result should be that order number greater than 4 should be update by (10-minutes) till 12 (order sequence) and greater than 9 should be updated by (5-minutes) till 12 (order sequence)

Right now I am using a while loop to resolve it by selecting each row of table-2 and updating table-1 time.

Is it possible to achieve it using joins?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cross apply`:

```
Update Table-1
    set .Time= DATEADD(minutes, t2.delta, t1.time)
from [Table-1] t1 cross apply
      (select top 1 t2.*
       from [Table-2] t2
       where t1.Typename = t2.Typename and
             t1.Ordersequence >= t2.ordersequence
       order by t2.ordersequence desc
      ) t2;
```

The problem that you are having is that multiple rows match in `Table-2`.  In that case, one of the rows is arbitrarily chosen for the update.  The `cross apply` fixes this problem by choosing the first row that matches.

Answer (score 0):

seems you have wrong sintax   (update don't have from clause and the table/join  must be indicated before set )

```
Update Table-1
 inner Join Table-2 on Table-1.TynameName=Table-2.Typename 
        and Table1.Ordersequence>=table-2.ordersequence
SET Table-1.Time= DATEADD(minutes,,table-2.delta,table-1.time)
where table-2.ordersequence != 9
;
```

Comment: Hi even after using the same syntax I get the above issue.

Comment: My result should be that order number greater than 4 should be update by (10-minutes) till 12 (order sequence) and greater than 9 should be updated by (5-minutes) till 12 (order sequence)

Comment: Hi Scais, 
Update Table-1
 inner Join Table-2 on Table-1.TynameName=Table-2.Typename 
        and Table1.Ordersequence>=table-2.ordersequence
SET Table-1.Time= DATEADD(minutes,,table-2.delta,table-1.time)
where table-2.ordersequence != 9
; 
I can't  hard-code the sequence number it can be any sequence number.